# PUT request to django tastypie resource not working

Tags: python, django, rest, put, tastypie

i'm trying to do a put request to my django tastypie resource in order to update user info. Up to now, i can make post request but put is not working.

In my api.py i have this:

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
   class Meta:
       queryset = User.objects.all()
       resource_name = 'auth/user'
       fields = ['username', 'email']
       authentication = BasicAuthentication()
       authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
       filtering = {
           "username": ('exact',),
       }

class UserSignUpResource(ModelResource):
   class Meta:
       object_class = User
       resource_name = 'register_user'
       fields = ['username', 'email' , 'password']
       allowed_methods = ['put','post']
       authentication = BasicAuthentication()
       authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
       queryset = User.objects.all()


    def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):

         bundle = super(UserSignUpResource, self).obj_create(bundle)
```

And to test i'me using this:

```
import urllib2, json

def post():

    def basic_authorization(user, password):
       s = user + ":" + password
       return "Basic " + s.encode("base64").rstrip()

    data = json.dumps({'username':'david_000', 'email':'davidupdat@gmail.com',   'password':'xxx','provider':'twitter','extra_data':{'access_token':'xxx','id':'xxx'}})

    req = urllib2.Request("http://192.168.1.114:8080/api/stats/register_user/",
    headers = {"Authorization": basic_authorization("xxx","xxx"),"Content-Type": "application/json"}, data = data)
    req.get_method = lambda:'PUT'
    f = urllib2.urlopen(req)

post()
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 18, in <module>
   post()
File "test.py", line 16, in post
   f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
   return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 406, in open
   response = meth(req, response)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 519, in http_response
   'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 444, in error
   return self._call_chain(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
   result = func(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 527, in http_error_default
   raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: BAD REQUEST
```

UPDATE:

i try this, but it gives me the same error:

```
def obj_update(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):

    bundle = super(UserSignUpResource, self).obj_update(bundle)
```

Any idea? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: How its not working? What server returns? What error?

Comment: sorry @Aldarund, question update.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because you are trying to issue a put request, but put request goes for update record and not a creating new one. Tastypie will try to execute obj_update method and it expects to be executed on some instance. But you are making request to register_user/ url which is obviously is not an object instance,  so it doesnt make a sense at all to use put request for this url. PUT is for updating, not creating.

Comment: what is in response body ?

Comment: didnt see anything. just error stack from you code. But you need to show response body.

Comment: [15/May/2013 11:42:07] "POST /api/stats/register_user/ HTTP/1.1" 400 36
is this what you want?

Comment: Nope.. You are showing headers. What inside. What actually server returns. 400 response also return body like a normal 200 request. That i want. Content of the response

Comment: Ok, how can i get that information? Because server only shows [15/May/2013 11:42:07] "POST /api/stats/register_user/ HTTP/1.1" 400 36 and traceback in console...

Comment: you can get it with http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html this lib. With accessing property content

Comment: I try to use requests lib and print request status,history and content and it shows me only this: status_code= 400, history=[], content={"error": "Invalid data sent."}

Comment: Yep. The Invalid data sent is the repsonse body.  Ok. The put method to this url calls the put_list method which expects objects to be replaced as json. And it didnt find it and return invalid data error

Comment: Hmm, ok... Anyway, if i try to make a post request with the same data, response body tells me this: "username already exists."... What can i do to solve this and allow resource to accept updates?

Comment: post mean create. put update. But put should be executed againts instance, against UserResource (with url with id of instance)  not a UserSignUpResource

Comment: And if i want to do something like this: http://0.0.0.0:8080/api/stats/auth/user/davidr/?format=json
instead of this: http://0.0.0.0:8080/api/stats/auth/user/1/?format=json, in order to update an instance, what i have to configure?

Comment: With that url it will replace the whole collection, not update one of it. If you want to update one entry you should use user/1  its a REST way

Comment: Ou. Sorry misread your question.. if you want username isntead of id read this: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#using-non-pk-data-for-your-urls

Comment: it gives me the following error: global name 'url' is not defined

Comment: Please put clarifications and caveats to the question into the question.  Please put clarifications and caveats to this answer into this answer. Comments can be deleted at any time for any reason.

Answer (score 3):

I just solve it with some modifications. Using hydrate method i can catch the request method (like put ou post) and process my requests. Like this:

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
   class Meta:
       queryset = User.objects.all()
       resource_name = 'auth/user'
       fields = ['username', 'email','password','extra_data','provider']
       authentication = BasicAuthentication()
       authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
       filtering = {
            "username": ('exact',),
       }

   def prepend_urls(self):
       return [
           url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<username>[\w\d_.-]+)/$" % self._meta.resource_name, self.wrap_view('dispatch_detail'), name="api_dispatch_detail"),
       ]

   def hydrate(self, bundle):
       request_method=bundle.request.META['REQUEST_METHOD']

       if request_method=='POST':
          #do something if you want
       elif request_method=='PUT':
          #do something if you want
       return bundle
```

And to test i've created a python file with this:

```
def basic_authorization(user, password):
    s = user + ":" + password
    return "Basic " + s.encode("base64").rstrip()

url = 'http://192.168.1.114:8080/api/stats/auth/user/david/'
payload = {'username':'david', 'email':'david__@gmail.com', 'password':'xxxx','provider':'twitter','extra_data': {'access_token':'xxxx','id':'xxx'}}
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.put(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('xxx', 'xxx')) 

print r.status_code
print r.history
print r.content

post()
```

And it worked!