# Django Tastypie Update, Delete Sample

Tags: django, tastypie

I have implemented Create, but could not figure out how to make Update, Delete to work. Can someone provide COMPLETE sample illustrate how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

you can look at these answer for UPDATE, to update data you have to use PUT. 
[PUT request to django tastypie resource not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16567608/put-request-to-django-tastypie-resource-not-working) and to delete data [***obj_delete](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#id15). See this already answered one to delete data [Tastypie return data from DELETE requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23482183/tastypie-return-data-from-delete-requests)

Comment: Appreciate your reply!